# Laravel WHERE on same column

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How I can query using Laravel Eloquent the following:

```
->where('items.type',"shirt")
->where('items.type',"glass")
```

I need to get the items with the type of **shirt** and **glass**

The above works with 1 Where on the same column. If I place the 2nd Where (glass), nothing is returned.

My desired query, as SQL:

```
WHERE items.type == "shirt" || items.type == "gass"
```

Comment: if it is a hasManyThrough relation, then you have to do ->whereHas('items.type',"shirt"), ->whereHas('items.type',"glass") or item.type is a name of a column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `orWhere` method.

```
->where('items.type', 'shirt')->orWhere('items.type', 'glass')
```

It's documented on https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#where-clauses.

> You may chain where constraints together, as well as add `or` clauses to the query. The `orWhere` method accepts the same arguments as the `where` method:

You can also use the `whereIn` method.

```
->whereIn('items.type', ['shirt', 'glass'])
```

> The `whereIn` method verifies that a given column's value is contained within the given array:

Answer (score 0):

If you want a OR condition, you should wrap it within a where!

```
->where(function($query){
   $query->where('items.type',"shirt")->whereOr('items.type',"glass");
});
```

OR

```
->whereIn('items.type', ['shirt', 'glass'])
```